# Custom vanilla JS for translation does not work on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, localization

I've been really struggling to use any (literally any!) client-side (e.g. web browser) translation library. Tested several: jquery-i18next, jquery.i18n, localizejs, translate-js. And guess what - none really worked as expected, not a single one would be just a plug-n-play solution. That's why I decided to write a vanilla Javascript code which would work as a simplest alternative. Here's the code:

```
let locale;

let dict = {
  'en': {...},
  'fr': {...}
};

function detectNavigatorLocale() {
  const languageString = navigator.language || '';
  const language = languageString.split(/[_-]/)[0].toLowerCase();

  switch (language) {
    case 'en':
      return 'en';
    case 'de':
      return 'de';
    default:
      return 'en';
  }
}

// replacement to $(document).ready() in jQuery
function docReady(fn) {
  // see if DOM is already available
  if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
    // call on next available tick
    setTimeout(fn, 1);
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
  }
}

// helper to get nested value in JSON-like object by dot-path string
function findProp(obj, prop, defval) {
  if (typeof defval == 'undefined') defval = null;
  prop = prop.split('.');
  for (var i = 0; i < prop.length; i++) {
    if (typeof obj[prop[i]] == 'undefined')
      return defval;
    obj = obj[prop[i]];
  }
  return obj;
}

let switchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-locale]');

for (let i = 0; i < switchers.length; i++) {
  switchers[i].onclick = function () {
    let newLocale = switchers[i].getAttribute('data-locale');
    locale = newLocale;
    translate();
  };
}

function translate(newLocale) {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-i18n]');

  for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    let path = els[i].getAttribute('data-i18n');
    let translatation = findProp(dict[locale], path, 'undefined');
    els[i].innerHTML = translatation;
  }

  // trigger repainting
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
};


docReady(function () {
  locale = detectNavigatorLocale();
  translate();
});
```

And to make it work, the only thing to do in HTML is to add attributes to the elements which require translation as `<p data-i18n="some.path.in.dictionary">fallback text</p>`. To change the language I used `<li data-locale="en">EN</li>` and similar.

But here's the tricky part: why Desktop browser shows expected results, but several tested mobile browsers refuse to a) emit event on the locale switcher element and b) in some (Brave, Dolphin) even navbar in collapsed state does not unfold. I expect that latter is related to the JS handling in general in the selected browser, but why in Chrome for example the same code does not work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I replaced the bad practice of setting `onclick` with the following:

```
function switchLocale(loc) {
    locale = loc;
    translate();
}

let switchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-locale]');

switchers.forEach(
    function(switcher) {
        switcher.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // alert(switcher.id);
            switchLocale(switcher.getAttribute('data-locale'));
        })
    }
)
```

and tested that it works fine. But the actual problem was that `z-index` was too low and the image below was overlayered above mobile nav. :)